# Cast struct with different fields into array of uint8's

Tags: c++, networking, casting, udp

I'm searching for a method how to cast a struct with individual fields like:

```
struct myStruct{
uint16_t x1;
uint32_t x2;
uint8_t x3;
double x4[12];
uint8 x5[12];
...
}
```

into an array of uint8 bytes for the purpose of transmitting it via UDP.
No precision should be lost during the cast.
The contents of the struct are nested in an special message format, containing only uint8:
preamble (2xuint8) | identifier (1xuint8) | struct in uint8 (see above) | checksum (2xuint8)

Can you recommend me a method how to do this?

Comment: What you plan to do is called "serializing". There are many posts in SO, explaining the howto. You should not cast or do some other magic. The struct may be padded, meaning, there is no must for contiguous memory. I recomend to add a serialization function and to convert part by part. For example, you define a std::ostringstream, put everything in the ostringstream via << and then use the ostringstream str().c_str() function to access the data. That is one of many possible solutions . . .

Comment: It is totally legal to inspect instances of your struct through a `uint8*`. As long as the stuff in `...` is similarly trivial, it is also legal to `memcpy` the struct around. **However**, for networking this is insufficient - different platforms may have e.g. different endianness, different struct packing and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
auto byteArray = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&myStructInstance);
```